# React Context API vs Redux for middle-scale projects

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-context

I'm planning to create a new project which is something like management system panel for my company's license. I will use React for my client side and I would like to use state management system but not sure about which should i use. So my question is: which state management should i use. I already examine redux and context api. Redux is fine but i feel that is quite complex and overwhelm for a middle size projects. On the other hand context api fine but not well documented like redux. Also redux need extra libraries like saga or thunk. If u suggest redux which library should i use for middle scale project?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your project this is not a question that can be answered. If you know what redux is and why it works the way it does you can answer your own question because you know why redux is not context api. Anyone answering telling you that you should use one or the other should never be in charge of any project.

Comment: Keep in mind that Redux uses the Context API behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go with context, because context-api more clear and more understandable for middle-scale projects.

Comment: Yes, my think is that too. But what if I decided to go with Redux when i use context. It will hard or easy to implement? What you think?

Comment: I think not so hard